# Безопасное присваивание и получение свойства из объекта

Tags: javascript

У меня есть объект конфигурации, по умолчанию он пустой

```js
const config = {}
```

Любой участок приложения может запросить любое поле объекта и будет ожидать верный тип, либо `undefined`

```js
const theme = config.appearance.theme ?? 'light'
```

Так как по умолчанию поле `appearance` отсутсвует, то **невозможно прочитать свойство `theme` у `undefined`**
Следующий код уже будет работать как ожидается

```js
const theme = config.appearance?.theme ?? 'light'
```

Но некоторый участок программы может установить значение. Теперь проблем гораздо больше

```js
config.appearance.theme = 'dark' // TypeError: config.appearance is undefined
config.appearance?.theme = 'dark' // SyntaxError: invalid assignment left-hand
```

В голову приходит идея с `Proxy`, но вот что-то не получается.

```
const proxy = (target) => new Proxy(target, {
  get(target, key) {
    target[key] = target[key] ?? proxy({})
    return target[key]
  }
})

const config = proxy({})
```

Установка значения вроде работает

```js
config.foo.bar.baz = 16
console.log(config.foo.bar.baz) // 16
```

Ошибок нет, но не работает, так как возвращает объект `Proxy` на каждое несуществующее свойство, а должен только на те свойства у которых не удаётся прочитать конечное свойство

```js
console.log(config.a.b.c ?? 10) // undefined
```

В общем что я ожидаю. Что если невозможно прочитать свойство, то вернётся undefined и объект не будет модифицирован как в примере. При попытке установить свойство по несуществующему пути, то все свойства не включая конечное будут установлены на пустой объект

Comment: Для вас будет проблемой, если к объекту надо будет обращаться через функцию? Если нет, то можно объявить функцию типа `propertyOfConfig`, где первым аргументом будет строка, которая отвечает за нужное поле любой глубины типа `'a.b.c.d'`, а вторым необязательным аргументом будет значение. Если значение установлено, то оно будет присвоено, если нет, то вернётся только уже существующее значение или `undefined`. Можно даже 2 функции объявить один будет `getPropertyOfConfig`, а другой `setPropertyOfConfig`

Comment: @EzioMercer Желательно конечно без них, но придётся, если другого выхода нет

Comment: Можно наверное даже класс `Config` объявить, чтобы "спрятать" функции в методы и тогда не будет возвращено `Proxy` при обращении к свойствам, но в целом ничего не изменится. Почему я советую использовать класс, чтобы не было прямого неконтрольного доступа к переменной `config`

Comment: @EzioMercer Да, класс можно, у меня в приложении MobX для управления состоянием и singleton сервис `DataStorage` со свойством `config`